# Getting distorted layout of bottom layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make a bottom layout like in the image 1.

[image: correct image]

But when application works, the bottom layout gets stretched on big screen like in image 2:
[image: incorrect image]

Here is the source...

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@layout/footer_color"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_layout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1.0"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/bottom_layout11"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:background="@drawable/profile_01"/>
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/bottom_layout12"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:background="@drawable/profile_01"/>
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/bottom_layout13"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.2" 
    android:gravity="center"
   android:background="@drawable/profile_01"/>
 <Button 
    android:id="@+id/bottom_layout14"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/profile_01"/>
  <Button 
    android:id="@+id/bottom_layout15"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/profile_01"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

required- footer layout with equal space on all resolution without stretching.

I am not getting where should i improve the code. please reply .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you hardcoding the height of relative layout to 50dp..let it be wrap_content and just use images of proper size..

Comment: giving same result @Vikram

Comment: Also note that the outer RelativeLayout is useless and fattens the hierarchy.

Comment: hmm got that @DerGolem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

Note : please put respective images on all size drawable folder.

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@layout/footer_color"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bottom_layout11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/profile_01"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bottom_layout12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/profile_01"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bottom_layout13"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/profile_01"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bottom_layout14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/profile_01"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bottom_layout15"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/profile_01"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to support different screens then you need to provide images and values according to the screens.

Create `values` and `drawable` for each screen sizes. Specify your height and width in values folder if you want to use custom otherwise make it as `match_parent` and `wrap_content`.

You need to create four folder

```
 values-ldpi // Small Screens
 values-mdpi  // Medium Screens
 values-hdpi // Large Screens
 values-xhdpi // Xtra Large Screens
```

Also you need to use correct image sizes. For sizes please check [Android Support Mulitple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: i know this but i what to do as given in question (different method...mmm i guess)...

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@layout/footer_color"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_layout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1.0"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="0.2"
       >
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/bottom_layout11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:background="@drawable/profile_01"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="0.2"
       >
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/bottom_layout12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
       android:background="@drawable/profile_01"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="0.2"
       >
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/bottom_layout13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
       android:background="@drawable/profile_01"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="0.2"
       >
     <Button 
        android:id="@+id/bottom_layout14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/profile_01"/>
    </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="0.2"
       >
        <Button 
        android:id="@+id/bottom_layout15"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/profile_01"/>
         </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

share the output..